# Java: Use the classes Job and IJobManager with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jobs

I'm developping a java program with eclipse and I would like to use the classes Job and IJobManage

```
IJobManager jobMan = Job.getJobManager();
Job[] build = jobMan.find(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD); 
if (build.length == 1)
       build[0].join();
```

But eclipse don't regnognise this classes. Have I to add something to eclipse?
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have corresponding jars in your class path.

http://eclipse.org/rtp/downloads/ if i'm correct...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I downloaded the zip file of eclipse RT package. How to include that to my project?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin needs to have the `org.eclipse.core.jobs` plugin in its dependencies list.